# Do we need playstaion+ or playstation network membership to play online even if we have WiFi

Tags: ps4

I've heard that a PlayStation+ membership is required to play online. I have WiFi... do I also need a PlayStation+ membership? Or is a normal PSN account sufficient?

Comment: WiFi is needed to connect to the internet. PS+ is needed to play online (in addition to having a connection to the internet, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Online play is not a free service on the PS4.  You will likely need a Playstation+ membership and an internet connection.